# What is the easiest way to protect api routing in laravel5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Now, I am using Laravel Passport(4.0) in my project

But it's not working well in production environment.

I was thinking to stop using Laravel Passport.

Is there any way easier than using Laravel Passport?

Comment: In my case i used the JSON web token package (https://jwt.io/) for my api. After the initial login the token is generated and updated every 5 minutes. Works very well with laravel. You should give it a try. In my opinion it is also very leigthweight and better to use & understand than passport.

Comment: I dont know why you dont want to use passport but all the applications that I develop use passport. And there is no issues at all. Passport provides you the standard way of API authentication system. I have high traffic E-fax application which is based on API and customer consume the API fro their applications and clients. Post your issue with passport if you want to share.

Comment: @webDev I have difficulty in understanding how Passport work, in my development environment passport worked well with no tables like oauth_clients, but in staging environment not worked well so I added those table. But still, with those table not working well in production environment(on AWS ELB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always prefer to use `token` based security to protect my APIs. Use JWT(Json Web Tokens). Learn more about it - https://jwt.io/

Comment: Thank you Rudraksh, I don't use ajax login or something like that, I just want my api routes secured then jwt is OK for it?

Comment: Yes, it is ok. Take a look at this thread - 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-5-jwt-auth-route-specific-tokens?page=1